# Transparent gif not transparent?

Tags: html, css, png, transparent

I downloaded a transparent png from findicons.com, and I thought that if I placed this png on my html page, that has a gradient colored background, I would only see the icon (a down arrow in this case).
Instead, however, I see the icon and a white(ish) box surrounding the icon. Have tried setting the background style to transparent or inherit and border to none, but that does not seem to help.

I'm not sure what my problem is here. Is it the fact that I have a body background that is a gradient color ? Is it the fact that I'm using a PNG ? 
Is it because the icon I downloaded isn't transparent, even though the site where I downloaded it from says it is ?
Is it because I'm just starting out building a website ?

Please, any suggestions ?
Thanks.

This is a page where I'm trying to achieve this :
[Not working example](http://hanslammerts.servebeer.com/GPN2/application/init.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, your image is within button tag. Button tag have a default background. You can set the background of your button to none, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin,
That was it !
I thought that this button tag did not have much to do with the input type=button..

Changed the source and added style="background: none; border: none;", and now I only see the icon.

Thanks again !